# Storing Application Variables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

There seems to be three distinct methods of storing a variable that will be available for every request in an application:

1. Global.asax.cs

   ```
   public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
   {
       protected void Application_Start()
       {
           Application["SiteDatabase"] = new SiteDatabase();
       }
   }
   ```
2. OWIN:

   ```
   public partial class Startup
   {
       public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder Application)
       {
           Application.CreatePerOwinContext<SiteDatabase>(new SiteDatabase());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Static Container

   ```
   public static class GlobalVariables
   {
       private SiteDatabase _Database;
       public SiteDatabase Database
       {
           get { return _Database ?? new SiteDatabase(); }
       }
   }
   ```

What are the relative advantages of each method?

Comment: You seem to be asking quite some basic ASP.NET questions lately that have been (partially) answered on this site before. Can you try to show some research? Can you perhaps buy some ASP.NET book?

Comment: Don't forget the database and the `Cache` - that makes 5 now!

Comment: They sort have been answered, but not very definitively.  They seem basic but the issue is that since new functionality is constantly being rolled out (e.g. the new version of Identity/Entity Framework has a big focus on using OWIN), it is difficult to determine how new functionality affects the old way of doing things.  When I google these sorts of questions and find answers from 2004, it is difficult to tell what to believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order:

## Global.asax.cs

- Pros: Works in all ASP.NET apps, available statically so you don't have to flow the data around the app yourself.
- Cons: Not strongly-typed. Doesn’t automatically work in distributed environment.

## OWIN

- Pros: Works great in OWIN and flows across the app. Using statics is considered poor programming by some.
- Cons: Doesn't work if you're not using OWIN (e.g. Katana). Doesn’t automatically work in distributed environment.

## Static Container

- Pros: Works in all ASP.NET apps, available statically. Strongly-typed means no ugly casts
- Cons: It's static :) Doesn’t automatically work in distributed environment.

## Database

- Pros: Works in a distributed system
- Cons: Potentially very slow; can fail due to network issues; requires a lot more code to implement reliably. The data must also be serializable.

## Cache

- Pros: Similar to database, except much faster.
- Cons: Similar to database (but much faster), plus the cache isn't generally meant for long-lived objects, though the ASP.NET cache does offer that behavior (but at that point, why use the cache).

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for - I really appreciate it!